# How can I store the all datasets onclick in localstorage when instead of only one dataset with intention of persistence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

I'm trying to prevent the user from liking photos more than once when refreshing the page.

So the current **incorrect** flow is: click like on desired photo → number increments → refresh the page → *click like on desired photo* → *number increments* → *refresh the page* → *rinse & repeat*

The **correct** flow should be: *click like on desired photo* → *number increments* → *refresh the page* → *click like on desired photo* → *number decrements* → ***rinse & repeat***.

In the `handleLike()` and `handleDislike()` functions I've set the `like` and `dislike` items in the localstorage. I can also see the localstorage being set on the browser's `Application` tab.  However, the problem is that upon clicking `Like`, the values in localstorage only track values one at a time instead of tracking all of the ones that were clicked (liked/disliked).

This is what gets stored in localstorage when liking/disliking:

[image]

How can I make the change so that the **correct flow** mentioned above gets implemented?  I've hit a wall on this and not sure what to do.

```
const [userLikedPhotos, setUserLikedPhotos] = useState({});

const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId, userName) => {
    if(userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId]) {
        // dislike
        delete userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId];
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId).likes--;
        handleDislike(likedPhotoUserId, userName);

    } else {
        // like
        userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId] = true;
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId).likes++;
        handleLike(likedPhotoUserId, userName);

    }

    // Spread the userLikedPhotos to create a new object and force a rendering
    setUserLikedPhotos({...userLikedPhotos});
};

const handleLike = (likedPhotoUserId, userName) => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/like';

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    let data = {
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId,
        'userName' : userName,
        'liked' : liked
    };

    axios.post(url, data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp.data);
            localStorage.setItem('like', JSON.stringify(resp.data));
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

};

const handleDislike = (likedPhotoUserId, userName) => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dislike';

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    let data = {
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId,
        'userName' : userName,
        'disliked' : disliked
    };

    axios.post(url, data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp.data);
            localStorage.setItem('dislike', JSON.stringify(resp.data));
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

};



return(
  {
   gridData.map((photos, index) => {
    return (
        <>
           <span className="likesAmt">❤️ {localStorage.getItem('likes') !== null ? localStorage.getItem('likes') : photos.likes}</span>
           <Button variant="success" onClick={() => handleLikesBasedOnUserId(photos.UserID, photos.name)}>Like</Button><br/><span className="name">{photos.name} {localStorage.getItem('UserID') === photos.UserID ? <h6 className="you">(You)</h6> : null}</span>
        </>
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: You shouldn't store `like` information in localstorage, unless it is meant as personal preference (that is local to the browser/device one is using). Keep the data on the server, have your API report the like count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of all likes/dislikes instead of setting the data, you need first to read (getItem) what is already in your localStorage and then set what was already + new like/dislike:

```
axios.post(url, data, {headers})
    .then(resp => {
        const likes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('likes'));
        likes.push(resp.data);
        localStorage.setItem('like', JSON.stringify(likes));
    }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You can apply the same to dislikes.

Comment: I don't think this works as `.push()` isn't compatible with `JSON.parse()`